# Pass radio button value in the url

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a search button with a textbox and 3 radio buttons. What I want to do is pass the value of the selected radio button into the url once the user clicks the search button. Right now the only thing that shows in the url is whatever the user typed into the textbox. So if the user checks off the Games radio button and then hits search, in the url it would show something like m=games...

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="search-bar" id="search-bar" class="search-box" onkeypress="return submitEnter();"/>

<button onclick="redirect();" class="search-button">Search</button><br/>

<input type="radio" name="selection" value="Music" id="music-button" class="radio-button"><span class="radio-text">Music</span>

<input type="radio" name="selection" value="Books" id="books-button" class="radio-button"><span class="radio-text">Books</span>

<input type="radio" name="selection" value="Games" id="games-button" class="radio-button" ><span class="radio-text">Games</span>
```

JS:

```
function redirect() 
{
    var url = "mylink.com";

    url = url+"&q="+document.getElementById("search-bar").value;
    location.href=url;
}


function submitEnter() 
{
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) 
        keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) 
        keycode = e.which;
    else 
        return true;

    if (keycode == 13)
    {
        redirect();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't a *Radio Button* simply be passed as a *Query String* the value being the `&Value=` then selected be either `true` or `false`?

Comment: Do you have this wrapped in a form element?  Can you create a jsFiddle example?

Comment: I don't know @Greg, that's why I'm asking lol. This is kinda new to me. I thought it would be something so simply but I've been searching online for hours and can't find a solution.

Comment: @roughcoder, no its not wrapped in a form element

Comment: Is there a reason why you have not just done a normal <form> with inputs and a submit button.  It will naturally redirect the page with the form field values within the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless i am misunderstanding something you can just submit the form.  Wrap it within a `form` element and change the `button` to a `type="submit"`.

You can then ditch the js redirect and make the submitEnter function more DRY.

```js
function submitEnter(form) {
  var keycode;
  if (window.event)
    keycode = window.event.keyCode;
  else if (e)
    keycode = e.which;
  else
    return true;

  if (keycode == 13) {
    form.submit();
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="http://www.example.com">
  <input type="text" name="search-bar" id="search-bar" class="search-box" onkeypress="return submitEnter(this);"/>
  <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="selection" value="Music" id="music-button" class="radio-button"><span class="radio-text">Music</span>

  <input type="radio" name="selection" value="Books" id="books-button" class="radio-button"><span class="radio-text">Books</span>

  <input type="radio" name="selection" value="Games" id="games-button" class="radio-button"><span class="radio-text">Games</span> 
</form>
```